# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs not changing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap v2.1.1 and its tabbable feature.

**Problem:** When any of the tabs are clicked, the `tab-pane` does not change, although the state of the tab buttons `.tab` itself changes. In other words, the tab buttons appear depressed when you click on it, but the content that's supposed to change with the tabs do not. A `console.log()` shows that the click event is being fired. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<!-- Tab Bar -->
<div class="tab-bar">
    <div class="tab active" id="photos" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#photos">
        <p>Photos</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="details" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#details"
        ><p>Details</p>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Tab Panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="photos" class="tab-pane">Photos</div>
    <div id="details" class="tab-pane">Details</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.tab-bar').tab();
$('.tab-bar .tab').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
    console.log('show');
})
```

**JS Includes**

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doesn't the 'tab names' need to be a ul/li instead of nested div's? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of problems and concerns:

1. Your src for bootstrap-tab.js is directly linking to the Twitter Github page.  I do not believe this is intended to be a CDN for Twitter Bootstrap.  I believe this file is "eat your own dogfood", i.e. the Twitter Bootstrap Github page uses Twitter Bootstrap for its documentation and downloads.

   Since it is not intended as such, they could easily and at any time change the directory structure or version.
2. You are using both bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap-tab.js.  I believe that bootstrap.min.js includes bootstrap-tab.js and using both causes problems.  See the following post: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/twitter-bootstrap/XH_ttp_9yXg
3. I am also using `twitter bootstrap 2.1.1`.  I did not find `tab-bar` in `bootstrap.min.js`, `bootstrap-tab.js`, `bootstrap.css`.  Is it possible you are referencing 2.1.1 files and coding against an older version of Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: For points #1 and #2, I removed the link to `bootstap-tab.js` and is still facing the same problem. `.tab-bar` is a class that i defined myself for styling purposes. Does the bootstrap plugin require a certain class name for the div containing the tabs?

Comment: @Nyxynyx Are you trying to do the **Tabbable nav** like in this example http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs?  Yes, my understanding is Bootstrap does require specific class names (but of course you can provide additional styling), I would start with the example and then customize it myself.